# Subtract the same scalar from all elements in a sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Say I have a csr-matrix,`cossim`, representing the cosine-similarity of some data. Since I need a distance metric I can create that simply by `1-cossim` or `-(cossim-1)`i.e substract the value of each element from `1`, elementwise.

The issue is that it is not implemented thus I thought of doing it by creating a matrix with 1 all over, `ones`, and then calculate `distance = ones-cossim` (but I cannot figure out on how to create a "ones matrix" with the same shape, since `csr_matrix(np.ones(cossim.shape))` needs 600GB of memory)

1. Can't we do some elementwise substraction with a sparse matrix?
2. If not what is the best way to do so?

Comment: subtracting from every element including the zeros, or just from the nonzero elements?

Comment: For every element e.g`[0.5,0,1]` should become `[1-0.5,1-0,1-1] -> [0.5,1,0]`

Comment: This is going to make your matrix dense because every zero will be a one. It is not implemented to stop you from doing this thing. You should change how you're using this matrix downstream.

Comment: Then all you can do is make your sparse matrix dense, `1-cossim.A`, and work with a small problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the dense issue as well and think I have to find some kind of workaround